# GAE mapreduce: How to access counters when the counting is done?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I have a mapper pipeline where the map function increments a counter using

```
yield op.counters.Increment("mycounter")
```

But I don't know how to access the value of "mycounter" after the pipeline has completed. I have seen examples using a completion handler, but they seem to refer to an older mapreduce library, where one could actually define a completion handler.

My best guess is that I need to define a final stage in the pipeline that has access to the mapper pipeline's counters -- but how exactly?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137485/how-can-i-access-the-mapper-reducer-counters-on-the-output-stage

Comment: @Gilberto: Exactly what I'm looking for, though in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137485/how-can-i-access-the-mapper-reducer-counters-on-the-output-stage), this feature is not available right now. There's a feature request in their issue tracker ([Issue 208](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/issues/detail?id=208)), which is currently with status "Started". Please star it ;-)